# Update on class, based on rid of sub-query

Tags: orientdb

I want to do an update based on the@rid of a subquery.

`select max(Visits.@rid) from Customers where @rid = #27:1074`

returns the result `#14:112`

When I try the bellow code, the execution is successful, but no records are updated

`UPDATE Visits Set exit_at = sysdate() where @rid = (select max(Visits.@rid) from Customers where @rid = #27:1074)`

However, if i do

`UPDATE Visits Set exit_at = sysdate() where @rid = #14:112`

The record is update with the desired results.

What am I overlooking ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Visits Set exit_at = sysdate() where @rid IN (select max(Visits.@rid) from Customers where @rid = #27:1074)
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.